# How can I filter a search query with two includes/contains?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I can restrict it with one includes/contains and an id

```
explain SELECT "questions".*
FROM "questions"
INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "taggings"."question_id" = "questions"."id"
INNER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id"
WHERE ("tags"."name" IN ('Cats') AND "tags"."id" = 1);
```

Result

### QUERY PLAN

```
 Nested Loop  (cost=5.49..23.95 rows=1 width=1088)
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=5.49..15.67 rows=1 width=1092)
     Hash Cond: (taggings.question_id = questions.id)
     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on taggings  (cost=4.31..14.45 rows=7 width=8)
           Recheck Cond: (tag_id = 1)
           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_taggings_on_tag_id  (cost=0.00..4.30 rows=7 width=0)
                 Index Cond: (tag_id = 1)
     ->  Hash  (cost=1.08..1.08 rows=8 width=1088)
           ->  Seq Scan on questions  (cost=0.00..1.08 rows=8 width=1088)
  ->  Index Scan using index_tags_on_name on tags  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=4)
     Index Cond: ((name)::text = 'Cats'::text)
     Filter: (id = 1)
   (12 rows)
```

I can restrict it with the same include statement (where cat twice)

```
explain SELECT "questions".*
FROM "questions"
INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "taggings"."question_id" = "questions"."id"
INNER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id"
WHERE ("tags"."name" IN ('Cats')
AND "tags"."name" IN ('Cats'));
```

Result

### QUERY PLAN

```
 Hash Join  (cost=5.49..24.00 rows=1 width=1088)
   Hash Cond: (taggings.question_id = questions.id)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=4.31..22.79 rows=7 width=4)
        ->  Index Scan using index_tags_on_name on tags  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=4)
              Index Cond: ((name)::text = 'Cats'::text)
     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on taggings  (cost=4.31..14.45 rows=7 width=8)
           Recheck Cond: (tag_id = tags.id)
           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_taggings_on_tag_id  (cost=0.00..4.30 rows=7 width=0)
                 Index Cond: (tag_id = tags.id)
   ->  Hash  (cost=1.08..1.08 rows=8 width=1088)
         ->  Seq Scan on questions  (cost=0.00..1.08 rows=8 width=1088)
(11 rows)
```

When I try to filter by two includes, no results

```
explain SELECT "questions".* 
FROM "questions"
INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "taggings"."question_id" = "questions"."id"
INNER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id"
WHERE ("tags"."name" IN ('Cats')
AND "tags"."name" IN ('Dogs'));
```

Result

### QUERY PLAN

```
 Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0)
   One-Time Filter: false
(2 rows)
```

Comment: What is your question? And seriously, are all those quotes *really* necessary?

Answer (score 3):

If you expected something different, I assume you want to use OR not AND:

```
...
WHERE tags.name IN ('Cats')
OR tags.name IN ('Dogs')
```

Or combine the two lists into one list:

```
...
WHERE tags.name IN ('Cats', 'Dogs')
```

As you had it, it was logically impossible to be true, because there are no values in *both* lists (the intersection of your sets is empty).

Answer (score 0):

That was a *very* bad query. Here's what I wanted:

```
SELECT COUNT("questions"."id"), "questions"."title" FROM "questions"
INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "taggings"."question_id" = "questions"."id"
INNER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id"
WHERE ("tags"."name" IN ('Cats','Dogs'))
GROUP BY "questions"."id", "questions"."title"
HAVING COUNT("questions"."id") = 2;
```

The two being a variable that is equals the number of values in the array.